# Current scroll position in CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I would like to scroll to the certain view when it becomes in focus.
I thought I could use `onNestedScroll` but the problem is that it takes only the distance to scroll, not the absolute scroll value.
So, I can get where the view is using `getLocationInWindow` but I don't know how to get the Y scroll of the entire layout. I tried to use `AppBarLayout` `current offset`, but it only shows the scroll on the collapsing toolbar.